# jQuery scroll to a certain number of pixels (or other units) above a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that scrolls to a particular element. Problem is, the page scrolls all the way to the top of the element... I would like to have a bit of a "buffer" between the top of the page and the element. I am currently doing:

`$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top},"slow");`

Comment: Jezzes : `$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top - 300},"slow");`

Comment: Excellent. Thanks :) I figured it was easy, but wasn't sure. Put this as an answer an I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to help, added it as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jezzes : `$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $("#elementID").offset().top - 300},"slow");`